# Importing schema via <import> - "Imported schema has different targetNameSpace..."

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces, xerces-c

I cannot seem to get beyond this problem and I'd really like for it to work.  With my main schema, rfidImage.xsd, I want to import a schema that describes a MIME scheme for JPG based on base64.  I think I have tried every possible combination except the one that makes this work.  I can just give up and include the schema code from xmlmime.xsd into rfidImage.xsd, but I want to advance in my understanding a bit here.  The two schemas have different namespaces, so I should be good using import and not include.  So, my basic problem is this error message:

Imported schema 'xmlmime.xsd' has a different targetNameSpace 'http://www.quikq.com/xsd/rfidImage' from what's declared 'http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime'

I'm using an older version of Xerces (might be 2.6) on an IBM AS/400, V7R1 and C++, SAX2 parser.

rfidImage.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="http://www.quikq.com/xsd/rfidImage"
    xmlns="http://www.quikq.com/xsd/rfidImage" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.quikq.com/xsd/JPEGPicture"
    xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!-- Import a supporting document -->
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" 
               schemaLocation="xmlmime.xsd"/>
```

xmlmime.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
```

I'm lost for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of xmlmime.xsd are as you describe them, then you should not be getting the error message you report. The import you show and the schema document you show are consistent with each other.

One possible cause is an inconsistency between what you think is in xmlmime.xsd and what is actually there.  Have the contents of rfidImage.xsd been saved by accident into xmlmime.xsd?  I'd check for this by closing down all software and checking the contents; the number of times people in my vicinity have been bitten by looking at editor buffers instead of files on disk is past counting.

Another possible cause:  for some reason Xerces is not actually reading xmlmime.xsd but some other schema document.  I'd check for this by introducing a well-formedness error into the first few lines of xmlmime.xsd and verifying that Xerces raises an error when it tries to read the schema document.

If neither of these produces any forward motion, you might try pointing not to your local copy of the xmlmime schema document, but to the version at http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime.xsd -- in general, W3C encourages the caching of schema documents and the use of local copies, but for testing purposes it might shed some light on things.

Good luck.